# How to automatically read the header (variable names) from file in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a text file (1.txt) as follows:

```
age height
20  180
35  165
44  175
```

I can use

```
data dat1;
  infile '1.txt' firstobs=2;
  input age height;
run;
```

to read the file into SAS. My question is, is there an automatic way of reading the header (variable names), that is, age and height into SAS without using 'input'? If I have many variables, I don't want to specify them one by one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PROC IMPORT` with the `GETNAMES` and `DATAROW` options appropriately set...

See the SAS Documentation : http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000312413.htm

```
/* delimiter = '09'x is tab-delimited */
proc import datafile='1.txt' out=dat1 getnames=yes datarow=2 dbms=dlm delimiter='09'x;
run ;
```